# show data from database in line chart (google chart) laravel (php)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, charts

i'm trying to make line chart in laravel using google chart and get data from database mysql.

Question:
how can i passing variable $bmi and $visits in data.addRows? so that i can showing the data using line chart.

here my code (php):

```
 public function graphBmi($childName){
   $name = DB::table('tm_child')->select('Child_Name')->distinct()
       ->where('Child_ID', 'LIKE', '%' . $childName . '%')->first();

   $visit = DB::table('tm_Child')
       ->join('tr_visit', 'tm_child.Child_ID', '=', 'tr_visit.Child_ID')
       ->where('tr_visit.Child_ID', 'LIKE', '%' . $childName . '%')
       ->select('Visit_Date', 'tr_visit.Child_ID', 'Bmi_anak')
       ->distinct()->get();


   if (!is_null($visit)) {
       $visits = [];
       $bmi = [];
       $data[0] = array('day','counts');
       foreach ($visit as $tgl) {
           array_push($visits, $tgl->Visit_Date);
           array_push($bmi, $tgl->Bmi_anak);
       }

   }

       //  return $visit;
       echo json_encode($bmi);    //number
       echo json_encode($visits); //date visit
       return View::make('ProfilAnak.BmiAnak.seeBmi')->with('visits',$visits)->with('bmi',$bmi);
}
```

here script for showing the chart

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<script>
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

    function drawBackgroundColor() {


        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('date', 'Visit');
        data.addColumn('number', 'X');

        data.addRows([
             [new Date{{$visits}},{{$bmi}}]
        ]);

        var options = {
            hAxis: {
                title: 'Time'
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: 'Popularity'
            },
            backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out the solution to it ?